# Updating gdb with JSON?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, json

```
parcelsFC = os.path.join('temp.gdb',JsonDirectoryLocation)

arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(parcelsFC)
```

Created gdb with above code.

How can I add attributes to gdb with another JSON file?

Comment: The code that you have presented does not create a geodatabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an output feature class.

```
parcelsFC = os.path.join('temp.gdb',JsonDirectoryLocation)
outFc = os.path.join ("temp.gdb", "JsonFeatures")
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(parcelsFC, outFc)
```